# Finding the deepest child of each parent in an array using php

Tags: php, recursion, multidimensional-array

I hope you are doing well.
I recently encountered a problem while practicing PHP.

Given the array as follows:

```
$arr = array(
    "P1"=>array(
        "C1"=>array(
            "C11"=>array(),
            "C12"=>array(
                "C121"=>array()
            )
        )
    ),
    "P2"=>array(
        "D1"=>array(
            "D11"=>array(
                "D121"=>array(),
                "D122"=>array(
                    "D1221"=>array()
                )
            ),
            "D12"=>array()
        )
    ),
    "P3"=>array()
);
```

We have to find the deepest child of each parent.
Sample output as follows:

```
P1 => C121
P2 => D1221
P3 =>
```

I am very much new to PHP so I would be very thankful for your inputs.

Comment: You have already identified recursion as relevant (as you've added it as a tag), so have you done any research into how you can solve the problem?

Comment: I have tried recursion and it seems like the way to go however I keep ending up with all the empty arrays

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recursion (a function calling itself) is the solution to your problem.

What I am using here is an array of keys and saving the level of deepness. The higher, the deeper. At the end I sort the array (by value) backwards and return the first key name (which is the deepest) or empty, if there isn't one.

```
foreach($array as $key => $value) {
    echo $key, ' => ', findDeepestChild($value), PHP_EOL;
}

function findDeepestChild(array $array, int $level = 0): string {
    $keys = [];
    foreach($array as $key => $value) {
        $keys[$key] = $level;
        if(!is_array($value)) continue;
        if(!empty($value)) return findDeepestChild($value, ++$level);
    }
    arsort($keys);
    return array_key_first($keys) ?? '';
}
```

Gives the output of

> P1 => C121
> P2 => D1221
> P3 =>

Comment: Thank you for this. I've just started learning PHP and it's proving to be harder than I thought.
Also could you suggest somethings that would help me better?
Thank you again!

Comment: Recursion is hard for our brain, because we think and code an in a linear way. This answer may be simplified, but then not so easy to read. Here is a nice guide for [PHP recursion](https://www.elated.com/php-recursive-functions/).

Comment: I've been able to do recursion easily in other languages but php just wasn't working with me. Anyways, thank you!

Comment: If there is anything unclear or I should explain in more detail, please let me know.

Comment: No that's fine. Thank you very much! It is very much self-explanatory.